# Print multiple copies of the same RDLC report

Tags: c#, rdlc

I have a `RDLC` reports that print some data based on a certain query. What I'm trying to do now is to print the same report (with different data based on a different value for the primary key) multiple time without having different files to print.

Let's say I have 3 reports of 2 pages each, I want a single report of 6 pages.

I used to do that in `Crystal Report XI` simply by putting a group on my primary key but I haven't been able to replicate that in `Visual Studio Report Designer`.

I need a preview is possibile so I can't just print them one after another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging I actually solved my issue using `PdfSharp`.

It works wonderfully for me because I don't need multiple rdlc files, I just do a loop and then export all to pdf.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a combined report that loads the three reports as subreports.  There's loads of useful information at [gotreportviewer.com/subreports](http://gotreportviewer.com/subreports/).  It's easy if the three different reports are in three different .rdlc files.  The situation is slightly more complicated when you want to use the same .rldc file for more than one subreport in the same combined report.  A subreport has parameters passed to it, and gets its `DataSet` through the `SubreportProcessing` event handler.  The solution I came up with was to pass a ReportID parameter to the subreport; then, the `SubreportProcessing` event handler asks what the ReportID is, and passes back the `DataSet` appropriate for the report.

You may need to modify your reports slightly to make them work as both "main" reports and subreports.  Subreports don't print the header or footer, so if you had important data there you'll need to move that to the body of the report.  Also if you use the ReportID trick, then you may need to modify the report to take the ReportID parameter.

Good luck!